# Chatbot: generative model using Python framework deployed in Slack

Tags: tensorflow, slack-api, chatbot

Could somebody tell me whether it is possible to develop a chatbot using python ML frameworks such as tensorflow and deploy in Slack using Slack's apps?

As far as I have read we could develop some retrieval based model using node.js. But I'm looking for a generative model.

Anything to help me get started is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use a generative model you have to use **tensorflow sequence to sequence architecture** . Here's the [official TF tutorial](https://github.com/tensorflow/nmt) from TF on sequence-to-sequence architecture .

So after training the model you can set this as an API which is easy. Then may be you can set it with the slack API for sure.